# Proof that two wave functions represent the same state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-states

How can I proof that the following two wave functions

$$\phi_n(x)=A \sin{\frac{n\pi}{L}x},$$ and

$$\psi_n(x)=\begin{cases}  B\cos \frac{n \pi}{L}x & n \text{ odd}\\ C\sin \frac{n\pi}{L}x & n \text{ even}\end{cases}$$

for $n=1,2,3,...$ belong to the same equivalence class, i.e. represent the same quantum state? 
In other words, I should proof that the functions are equal up to a phase shift, in accordance with the first postulate of quantum mechanics.

The question arises from the infinite potential well: the first family of functions is the solution of the Schrodinger equation for a potential centered in the origin, the second one comes from a shifted potential.

I tried applying the Euler's formula, but I did not manage to figure it out.

Here is my attempt, let us assume $L=1$, and $n=1$:

$$\phi_1(x)=A\sin \pi x = \frac{A}{2i} \big ( e^{i \pi x}-e^{-i \pi x}\big )$$

$$\psi_1(x)=B\cos \pi x = \frac{B}{2} \big ( e^{i \pi x}+e^{-i \pi x}\big )$$

Since the two wave functions must be the same unless a term of the form $e^{i\theta}$,

$$-iA \big ( e^{i \pi x}-e^{-i \pi x}\big )= e^{i\theta}B \big ( e^{i \pi x}+e^{-i \pi x}\big ).$$

Somehow the x should disappear from the equation, but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: That's not what the invariance w.r.t. phase shifts means (it would take your $\phi_n(x)$ to $e^{i\theta}A\sin(n\pi x/L)$ instead).

Comment: It is exactly what I meant. Hence I should somehow proof that $\phi_n(x)=e^{i\theta}\psi_n(x)$, since the two weve functions are solutions of the same problem. Right?

Comment: These wavefunctions cannot be the same because they have different boundary conditions. What you could show is that if you shift the whole well by $L/2$, only *then* they are equal.

Comment: @Dante No, that is not correct. Both $\phi_n$ and $\psi_n$ are real-valued; no global phase will transform one to the other (as your added maths shows), and they are **not** solutions to the same problem. They are solutions to displaced versions of the same problem and they are related by a displacement, but they are not equivalent without an explicit spatial translation.

Comment: Ok, now I see it. That is also analogous in classical mechanics indeed. Two identical systems shifted each other, will have the same energy but a measurement of a dynamic variable w.r.t. a common frame of reference, will not produce the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At $x = 0$ for odd $n$ we have
\begin{align}
\phi_n(x) &= 0\\
\psi_n(x) & = B\;.
\end{align}
Multiplying be $e^{\imath\theta}$ is never going to map these states onto each other. There is, however, a trivial relationship between these two states. Physically you have a square well from $0$ to $L$ in one case and a well from $-\frac{L}{2}$ to $\frac{L}{2}$ in the other. What would you expect you have to do to get from the states of one of these systems to the other?

Comment: Add $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to the sine argument for instance...

Comment: Right. A slightly more illuminating way to look at this is to say that since the 2 potentials are essentially the same except for a translation by $\frac{L}{2}$ what you need to to relate the states is apply the same translations. So define a change of coordinates $x= y + \frac{L}{2}$. Then $\phi_n(x) = A\sin\frac{\pi n}{L} x = A\sin \left(\frac{\pi n}{L} y + \frac{\pi n}{2}\right) = \psi_n(y)$. So the 2 wavefunctions are simply describing the same state in different coordinate systems.